# Simple Django Search Run on Django App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

In my Django project that aggregates NBA player stats (as a learning project), I've built a simple search view that allows you to search for players by first or last name (or both).  It works totally fine on the dev server, but now I want to deploy my site using Google App Engine, and I'm getting errors that I believe are due to GAE's High Replication Datastore.

I was under the impression that the [Django-nonrel/dbindexer](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/09/Get-SQL-features-on-NoSQL-with-django-dbindexer) tools would help alleviate this problem, but so far I've tried implementing them to no avail--when I attempt a search on my site, I get an error log with the message: 'DatabaseError: This query is not supported by the database.'

I'm guessing my problem might be that the instructions for these tools are spread across multiple docs written at different points in their development, so it's tricky for me to put them together into one coherent picture.  Also, I've looked at the testapp they offer and it seems to be set up somewhat differently than their instructions would suggest.  So I'd like to ask two questions:

1) Is the view I've coded is even possible to use with GAE and Django-nonrel/dbindexer?  Here it is:

```
def search(request):
        query = request.GET.get('q','')
        querywords = query.split(' ')
        lname=''
        for word in querywords[1:-1]:
                lname += word+' '
        lname += querywords[-1]
        if query:
                if len(querywords)>1:
                        qset = (
                                Q(first_name__iexact=querywords[0]) &
                                Q(last_name__iexact=lname) 
                        )
                        exact_results = Player.objects.filter(qset).distinct()
                        if exact_results != []:
                                result = exact_results
                                qset = (
                                        Q(first_name__icontains=querywords[0])|
                                        Q(last_name__icontains=querywords[0])|
                                        Q(first_name__icontains=lname)|
                                        Q(last_name__icontains=lname)   
                                )
                                results = Player.objects.filter(qset).distinct()
                                results = results.order_by('last_name','first_name')
                        else:
                                qset = (
                                        Q(first_name__icontains=querywords[0]) &
                                        Q(last_name__icontains=lname)|
                                        Q(first_name__icontains=querywords[0])|
                                        Q(last_name__icontains=querywords[0])
                                )
                                results = Player.objects.filter(qset).distinct()
                                results = results.order_by('last_name','first_name')
                                result = ''
                else:
                        qset = (
                                Q(first_name__icontains=querywords[0])|
                                Q(last_name__icontains=querywords[0])   
                        )
                        results = Player.objects.filter(qset).distinct()
                        results = results.order_by('last_name','first_name')
                        result = ''
        else:
                results = []
                result = ''
        return render(request,'search.html', {
                'result':result,
                'results': results,
                'query': query,
                'querywords':querywords
        })
```

2) If it is possible to use, and my project in dev is structured as follows, what is the most parsimonious set of steps I can follow to make my search view work properly on GAE?

```
NBA/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    templates/
            (html files)
    players/
            __init__.py
            admin.py
            models.py
            tests.py
            views.py
            fixtures/
                    (some .yaml fixture files)
            static/
                    (css, js, and gif files)
```

Comment: what do you mean it works fine on the dev server?  It runs properly on dev_appserver?

Comment: I mean when I run my project using "python manage.py runserver", my code works exactly as I want it to.

Comment: I'm not clear whether you're running a django project or a django-nonrel project.  It sounds like you built a non-GAE django project, and are trying to get it to work on GAE.  The thing I'm confused about at the moment is that I would expect that if you set it up properly, you should see the same failure locally.  I don't see app.yaml or a django folder in your tree, which would be necessary for your GAE project.

Comment: You are right; I built a non-GAE project and am trying to port it over.  All of the info I have above is for my plain old Django project.  I didn't post what I've tried so far because it's sort of a Hodge-podge of stuff culled from multiple articles and the testapp example.  I was hoping someone could give me a more unified set of steps to port my project, but it sounds like that may not be possible.

Comment: I don't really know, but my suggestion is to rewrite the app with simple non-relational queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after fiddling around with different kinds of queries using "python manage.py remote shell", I've come to the following conclusions:

1) As @dragonx mentioned, Q objects with "OR" are not supported.

2) However, Q objects with "&" definitely are.

3) The problem with my search view code, other than the "OR" queries, was the addition of "distinct()" in my "Player.objects.filter()" call.  Apparently the HRD doesn't support "distinct()", and this was responsible for the cryptic

"DatabaseError: This query is not supported by the database"

message.  By contrast, attempting to use a Q object with "OR" gives a much more helpful

"DatabaseError: Only AND filters are supported"

Now that I've removed the "distinct()" bit from my code (and any "OR"-containing Q objects), the search works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, JOINs are not supported, so all the Q objects with ORs probably won't work.

I haven't used dbindexer much, so I'm not sure how capable it is.  I do think if you use it, it will make your datastore queries expensive with all the extra indexing it tries to do automatically.

Even if you're using django-nonrel, you can't expect to port a django app over directly if it uses relational data.  You'll have to restructure your data and queries to be non-relational.

Comment: The thing is, I can't even get the Q objects with "&" to work.  That's why I feel as though I must not have set something up correctly.

Comment: I haven't tried Q objects, so I don't know if they work at all.